# unable to access reactive nested object returned by useFetch in <script setup> but i am able to access in the html

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

So I am trying to create a flow where there is a form, when they user modifies the form useFetch is triggered and the results on the page update. things are mostly working well i am able to access the `currentPokemon` variable within the html and reactivity is working great. The issue is that I am trying to access parts of `currentPokemon` from within the  so that the chart i define will also be reactive.

The `graph_data` show in the below is in the currentPokemon object, but i cant access it from within `<script setup>`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from 'chart.js'
import { Scatter } from 'vue-chartjs'

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Tooltip, Legend)

const units = ref('METRIC')
const friction = ref(1)
const payload = ref(1)
const distance = ref(1)
const time = ref(1)
const gearRatio = ref(1)
const motionProfile = ref(0.25)
const conservatism = ref(1.5)
const stage = ref('DEFAULT')


const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true
}


const { data: currentPokemon } = await useFetch(`http://localhost:3000/`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: {
    unit_system: units,
    motion_profile: motionProfile,
    move_time_sec: time,
    move_distance_deg: distance,
    friction: friction,
    payload: payload,
    gear_ratio: gearRatio,
    safety_factor: conservatism,
    be_stage: stage,
    manufacturers: ["Bosch"],
    motor: "DEFAULT"
  }
})

console.log(typeof(currentPokemon))
console.log(currentPokemon)
console.log(currentPokemon.graph_data)

const test = ref(currentPokemon.value)
console.log("test")
console.log(typeof(test))
console.log(test.graph_data)

const data = ref({
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Accel Profile 0.25 User',
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      // tension: 0,
      showLine: true,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        {x: user_graph.x[0], y: user_graph.y[0]},
        {x: user_graph.x[1], y: user_graph.y[1]},
        {x: user_graph.x[2], y: user_graph.y[2]},
        {x: user_graph.x[3], y: user_graph.y[3]}
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

here is the console output

```
✔ Vite server hmr 6 files in 54.932ms                                                                                                                         13:56:25
object                                                                                                                                                        13:56:25
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function                                                                                                13:56:25
  at <App>
RefImpl {                                                                                                                                                     13:56:25
  __v_isShallow: false,
  dep: undefined,
  __v_isRef: true,
  _rawValue: {
    motormatch: {
      '1': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '10': [Object]
    },
    stage_details: { DEFAULT: [Object] },
    motioncalcs: {
      '0.5': [Object],
      '0.33': [Object],
      '0.1': [Object],
      '0.25 User': [Object]
    },
    graph_data: {
      xlabel: 'Time (s)',
      ylabel: 'Velocity (deg/s)',
      title: 'Move Profiles',
      profiles: [Array]
    }
  },
  _value: {
    motormatch: {
      '1': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '10': [Object]
    },
    stage_details: { DEFAULT: [Object] },
    motioncalcs: {
      '0.5': [Object],
      '0.33': [Object],
      '0.1': [Object],
      '0.25 User': [Object]
    },
    graph_data: {
      xlabel: 'Time (s)',
      ylabel: 'Velocity (deg/s)',
      title: 'Move Profiles',
      profiles: [Array]
    }
  }
}
undefined                                                                                                                                                     13:56:25
test                                                                                                                                                          13:56:25
object                                                                                                                                                        13:56:25
undefined
```

Again the goal is to have the paramater passed to the graph be reactive based on the value of `currentPokemon.graph_data`. I have tried using let to declare new variables and access graph_data that way, which did allow me to get the value of graph_data but it was no longer reactive.

```
console.log(typeof(currentPokemon))
let res_data1 =  currentPokemon.value
let graph_data1 = res_data1.graph_data
let user_graph = graph_data1.profiles[3]
console.log(user_graph)
```

addition note, in html `{{ currentPokemon.graph_data }}` works perfectly and is reactive...

Comment: I fear that your asynchronous call, `async useFetch(...)`, won't have returned a value at the time that setup code is called. Since the useFetch(...) composable returns a promise, can you instead attached a .then(...) block and use the currentPokemon value from this block? This way the async result will have returned a value (or an error).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is there a way i can set it with a default value so that it is there on setup and point it to currentPokemon for an update?

Comment: Yes, perhaps declare `const currentPokemon = ref({...})` where `{...}` is an object with default values that you write out. Then assign the value to currentPokemon.value in the promise's `.then(...)` block.

Comment: But note that I am not a JavaScript or Vue.js expert, but rather I'm fairly new to this. Which is why I'm writing this as comment rather than as a gold-standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `ref` or `computed` the way you access values `template` vs `script` differs, in `script` you must use the `value` key accessor, in `template` you omit it because in templates the `value` key accessor is injected at compilation run-time.

```js
<script setup>
const myVar = ref([]) // Array

console.log(myVar.value.length) // Outputs 0

myVar.value.push('hello')

console.log(myVar.value.length) // Outputs 1

const count = computed(() => myvar.value.length)

myVar.value.push('world')

console.log(count.value) // Outputs 2

</script>

<template>

  <div>Total Items: {{ myVar.length }}</div>
  <div>Counter: {{ count.length }}</div>

</template>
```

---

However it is not the same case when working with nested reactive `reference` objects which is what you want to use if you are altering inner values of a nested object where you want to react to those nested alterations:

```js
<script setup>
const myObject = reference({
  myData: [] // Array
})

console.log(myObject.myData.length) // Outputs 0

myObject.myData.push('hello')

console.log(myObject.myData.length) // Outputs 1

</script>

<template>
  
  <div>Total Items: {{ myObject.myData.length }}</div>

</template>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for the clear explanation. when comparing your method of reference()  and my example with computed() they seam to work the same way for the most part. is reference() more performant and therefor the standard?

Comment: `reference` is more costly because it has deep reactivity so changing items inside a nested object achieves reactivity, `ref` is more performant but it is shallow reactivity, altering values in a deep object using `ref` will not react, you only get a reaction if you reassign the entire object directly on the `ref`.
`computed` leverages caching where on reactive update if reactive values used inside are detects as not being changed it returns what was computed on its first call.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this... I tried using reactive and a few other methods but this finally worked for me

```
/ Data pased to scatter plot
const data = computed({
   get() {
    let res_data1 =  currentPokemon.value
    let user_graph = res_data1.graph_data.profiles[3]

    let dataset = {datasets: [
    {label: 'Accel Profile 0.5',
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'blue',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderWidth: 1,
      // pointBackgroundColor: ['#000', '#00bcd6', '#d300d6'],
      // pointBorderColor: ['#000', '#00bcd6', '#d300d6'],
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      fill: false,
      // tension: 0,
      showLine: true,
      data: [
        {x: 0, y: 0},
        {x: 0.5, y: 2},
        {x: 0.5, y: 2},
        {x: 1, y: 0}]},
    {label: 'Accel Profile 0.33',
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'orange',
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      // tension: 0,
      showLine: true,
      data: [
        {x: 0, y: 0},
        {x: 0.33, y: 1.49},
        {x: 0.66, y: 1.49},
        {x: 1, y: 0}]
    },
    {
      label: 'Accel Profile 0.1',
      borderColor: 'green',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      // tension: 0,
      showLine: true,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        {x: 0, y: 0},
        {x: 0.1, y: 1.11},
        {x: 0.9, y: 1.11},
        {x: 1, y: 0}]
    },
    {
      label: 'Accel Profile 0.25 User',
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      // tension: 0,
      showLine: true,
      fill: false,
      data: [
        {x: user_graph.x[0], y: user_graph.y[0]},
        {x: user_graph.x[1], y: user_graph.y[1]},
        {x: user_graph.x[2], y: user_graph.y[2]},
        {x: user_graph.x[3], y: user_graph.y[3]}
      ]
    }
  ]}

    return dataset
  },
  // setter
  set(newValue) {
    // Note: we are using destructuring assignment syntax here.
    [firstName.value, lastName.value] = newValue.split(' ')
  }
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).